# Possible to merge two xcode apps in one?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, pdf

I have created a cordova app that needs to open pdf files stored within the app's assets.
I works with android but IOS overides the javascript meant to open the file and opens it with its core reader, leaving the user in a dead end (no back button, no save, no share, no nothing except the ability to close the apps, which is just great..)
After fruitlessly trying for days to force ios to present the pdf with a back button, I am now trying to use [PDF reader Core](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0ahUKEwjT58uc8ODTAhUGiRoKHTKuCTcQFghHMAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fvfr%2FReader&usg=AFQjCNGuyK4heXesmbMlxaZFlDxD41FEUQ&sig2=ZK08xrhIonFP_G05bD21Dw)  which seems a great tool to read pdf's. I would like to embed/merge PDF Reader Core within my Cordova app, so that it opens the pdf's it contains.

Is this feasible?
Thank you for any advice (step by step welcome :-))

P.S: I have tried the tutorials such as the Dev's Girl's and others but all are either deprecated, or show fatal errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also can create more than one target in your project, and check or uncheck targets for some file in inspector panel for sharing your code between targets. Every target is an app.

Comment: Thanks FreeGor! But is it possible to make it so that the pdf assets in App#1 are only opened by App#2?

Comment: Thanks FreeGor! Can we open a chat?

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found my view was mistaken.
It is not a secondary app I am looking for but a "framework".
I am now trying to work it out with some that are available.